# How to store continuous scale data in database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a very simple nodejs server (using Express) running locally on port 8000.
Using the npm package `serialport` I managed to connect to a scale and get it's weight in a continuously mode like so.

terminal output..

```
0 
10 
20 
30 
50 
50 stable
50 stable
...
```

I want to save the scale **stable** weight to a database (in my case MongoDB Atlas) but I don't want to make hundreds of requests as the scale weight changes.

I know tools like `RxJS` and one of it's operators `distictUntilChange` but I'm not using any client.

How this can be done working only with a server ?

Comment: Why bother involving a server? You want to hook up data from a serial port to a database. Why involve HTTP as well? That's like wanting to record sound so you build a recording studio with microphones and some data storage and attaching an airport to it. And if you aren't involving a client: Never flying any planes to it.

Comment: database is a cloud service and there are 20 scales in different locations, I want users from anyware to able to read the last stable weight of each scale.

Comment: @Quentin (My interpretation could be wrong, but) I'm pretty sure by "client"/"server" OP means browser/not-browser.

Comment: @jsejcksn — They talk about Express which is an HTTP server.

Comment: @user12163165 — If you want the Node.js program that is reading the scale to send data to the database, then it needs to act as a client for whatever the interface for the database is. There doesn't seem to be any reason for the program reading the scale and sending data to the database to be operating as an HTTP server.

Comment: @Quentin nodejs is running as a service on a local computer which is connected to the scale, I don't want the user on the computer to open its browser and send the request, there are people outside using the scale and once they put something on the scale I'd like to save it to the database which is a cloud service.

Comment: @user12163165 — You said that. So why is Express involved? The local service only needs to monitor the scale and send data to the database. You keep saying you don't want them to open a browser … but I've got no idea why you'd write it in such a way that a browser would be involved in the first place. (To rephrase your previous statement in terms of my music metaphor: "My studio has mics. I don't want to have to land planes at the airport. There are people singing, and when then sing into the microphone I'd like to record it")

Comment: @user12163165 As-is, the question doesn't contain enough information for someone to provide a relevant suggestion/answer, but if you can update it with some JavaScript details instead of just terminal output, then one might be possible. For example: you said you're using the [`serialport`](https://github.com/serialport/node-serialport) package, but how are you actually getting the data? Is it via an async iterator / event callback function, etc? What is the data structure of each reading (e.g. an object like `{ weight: number, stable?: boolean }`)?

Comment: @jsejcksn the question is not about data structure or the way to get it, the data is there. all I'm asking is how to save the data in a database cloud service (as mentioned in my question) `MongoDB Atlas` of course using HTTP.

Comment: They have documentation for node — https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/ — it still isn't clear what the problem you are having is.

Comment: @user12163165 So what's the actual question? (1) How to validate which weight values to send before uploading them? If so, you'll have to show some code to get a non-conceptual answer. Or is it (2) How to use Mongo Atlas from within Node.js? That question has already been asked and answered on this site.

Comment: @jsejcksn basically (1) How to validate which weight values to send before uploading them and make as fewer requests as possible. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't shown any code, here's a conceptual answer, which assumes that your readings are coming from an [async iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/asyncIterator) and that you already have a function for uploading each weight value. In this example, the `weight` property of each reading is a `number` and the `stable` property of each reading is a [nullish](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Nullish) `boolean`.

```js
async function uploadLoop (scaleReaderIterator, uploadWeight) {
  let previousWeight;

  for await (const {weight, stable} of scaleReaderIterator) {
    if (
      !stable || // the weight reading isn't stable, OR
      weight === previousWeight // the weight hasn't changed since last time
    ) continue; // don't do anything else in this code block
    // else

    // update the previous value
    previousWeight = weight;
    // upload it
    uploadWeight(weight);
  } // loop
}
```

Comment: I can't tell when it is stable or not, I'd like to check if value repeat is self for more then let's say 10 times. I like the direction you took.

Comment: @user12163165 Like I've said already in comments and in my question text: without some [reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), there's not much more I can offer. If you need to debounce the weights, I'd suggest doing it by computed time intervals instead of an arbitrary "last _n_ times" (which might itself be expressed as "every _n_ measurement" based on reading rate, but that's an implementation detail).